# Python-invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'N' Error

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, error-handling, integer

I have to read this csv file into a list and I have declared type int for writing certain columns in list as integer type but this error has become a problem for me.

```
with open('new_toy_dataset.csv','r') as cf:
 for row in cf:
      toy_list.append([int(row[0]), row[1], row[2], int(row[3]), int(row[4]), row[5]])
```

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eakj8.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZBuC.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Just take a small sample of your data and pack it into a code block and take the error message and quote it.

Comment: Alright Timus.
I am new here and kinda alien to the culture.

Comment: No problem! Have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not skipping the header.

```
import csv

toy_list = []
ind = 0

with open('new_toy_dataset.csv','r') as cf:
    reader = csv.reader(cf, delimiter=';') # whatever delimiter it is
    for row in reader:
        if ind == 0:
            ind += 1
            continue

        toy_list.append([int(row[0]), row[1], row[2], int(row[3]), int(row[4]), row[5]])
```

Comment: that certainly seems to be the case....thank you for the answer